# predict.glm using observed values in dataset

Tags: dataframe, prediction, glm, predict

I am building a predictive voter turnout model using a voter file called 'Nevada'. The model is a logit that uses 2020 turnout as a DV. Now I want to make 2024 predictions using that model.

I have been able to get individual predictions by running newdata = Nevada, but for some variables, like age, I want to use the newer 2024 value, whereas the model is predicted using the 2020 value. Then for variables that don't change over time (for instance, partyID), I still want to use the actual observed values for each individual.

In predict.glm, when it comes to newdata = "", instead of using only a few discrete values in the data.frame, I want the model to solve for the individual OBSERVED values in the file (all 2 million of them). Plus the twist that I want to plug and chug the values of a different variables for age.

Below, Republican and ActiveVoter are dummies, Age_2020 is interval and numeric:

```
TOmodel.ex = glm(D2020final ~ Republican + ActiveVoter + Age_2020,
          data=Nevada, family="quasibinomial")

summary(TOmodel.ex)
prediction.frame.2024 = data.frame(actual=Nevada$Republican, 
                               actual =Nevada$ActiveVoter, 
                               actual =Nevada$Age_2024)
TOpredictions.ex = predict.glm(TOmodel.ex,type="response", newdata=prediction.frame.2024)
```

The prediction frame seems to do what I want it to do, but on predict.glm, I know I have a syntax issue. I get this error:
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Republican' not found

What do I need to do in my data.frame argument to properly apply observed values to the TOmodel? THANK YOU!